# ModX. Пакет Login, авторизация пользователей. Пользователь не может завершить сессию

Tags: modx

У меня проблема с реализацией регистрации и авторизации пользователей. Сделала по этому пособию https://modx.ru/novosti-i-stati/article/63/, но с помощью       `<a href="[[+logoutUrl]]">Выход из профиля</a>` не завершается сессия. То бишь форма входа, аналогичная этой https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpi6T.png, снова появляется, но вот переменные типа [[+modx.user.id:userinfo=`fullname`]] все еще показывают имя того, кто первый залогинился после принудительного завершения сеансов в панели управления. Плюс в панели управления видно, что пользователь все еще онлайн, хотя я нажимала кнопку "Выход из профиля": https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y22Up.png. В чем дело? Как сделать, чтоб пользователь мог выйти из профиля?

Comment: Какую ссылку в итоге генерирует <a href="[[+logoutUrl]]">?
Ничего в логе MODX по этому поводу подозрительного не заметили? Менялись ли настройки сессий, заданные по умолчанию в MODX? настройки PHP по поводу сессий? Все эти вопросы так или иначе могут влиять на сессию пользователя в MODX

Comment: Все, спасибо, я разобралась сама - нужно было просто отключить кэширование настроек контекстов. Из-за кэша все данные предыдущего пользователя сохранялись.